# I have a list of integers. I am performing some action on the items of list and then print the result in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

> There is a list `t` with some temperatures in it. If the temperature is
>   greater than -273, then convert it to Fahrenheit and write the result
>   in a separate text file named `tmp.txt`

Below is my code.

```
t=[10,-20,-289,100]
def writer(input):
    with open("tmp.txt","w+") as f:
        for i in t:
            if i>-273.15:
                f=i*9/5+32
                f.write(f)
        f.close()
print(writer(t))
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "lst_input.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(writer(t))
  File "lst_input.py", line 7, in writer
    f.write(f)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'write'
```

How to write the result to tmp.txt file?

Comment: Does `f.write(f)` look alright?

Comment: Did you read what the error message is telling you?

Comment: You keep reusing `f` and erasing what it refers to. Suggest longer more descriptive  names, and don't overwrite them.

Comment: Your overwriting the value of your file handle. You need to rename your temperature computation to something else.

Comment: t=[10,-20,-289,100]
def writer(input):
    with open("tmp.txt","w+") as f:
        for i in t:
            if i>-273.15:
                j=i*9/5+32
                f.write(str(j))
        f.close()
print(writer(t))

This code works but doesn't write anything to tmp.txt file

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be manually calling `f.close()`. Since you're using a context manager, Python does that for you.

Comment: can someone please make the changes in this code? I have made some changes and it isn't working still. Please look at the code below

t=[10,-20,-289,100]
def writer(input):
    with open("tmp.txt","w+") as f:
        for i in t:
            if i>-273.15:
                j=i*9/5+32
                f.write(str(j))
print(writer(t))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the value directly, don't save it in the variable called f, because you are reference to a float instead to the file, also convert it as string with str, and don't close it, I forget, and finally read it like this:

```
t=[10,-20,-289,100]
def writer(input):
    with open("tmp.txt","w+") as f:
        for i in t:
            if i>-273.15:
                f.write(str(i*9/5+32))

text_file = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
file_contents = text_file.read()
print(file_contents)
```

Comment: there is no need for `f.close()`when using `with open` statement.

Comment: @olisch you saved my life! thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Damien, It works. Thanks :)

Comment: @myk Hi, I updated the answer, to read the value is diferent way!

Comment: @myk don't forget accept the answer if it works and you liked! top left with the  (✓)

Comment: I got the answer. Thank you very much Sir. :)

Comment: @myk you can only accept one answer don't forget

Comment: @damien ok sir :)

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same variable `f` (file object) to store the `float result`. Also you don't need to close the file (`f.close()`) as you are using a `context manager`. 
One more thing the variable input is not used inside the function. Instead you are using the variable `t`. For that `for i in t` should be `for i in input`

If you want to write each value in a separate line you need also to append `\n` to the written string `f.write(str(x) + '\n')`

```
t=[10, -20, -289, 100]
def writer(input):
    with open("tmp.txt","w+") as f:
        for i in input:
            if i > -273.15:
                x = i * 9 / 5 + 32
                f.write(str(x) + '\n')
print(writer(t))
```

Comment: Thanks saloua. I understood my mistake. :)